# www in domain return timeout, after I add redirect using regex in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx and I want to redirect non-www to www:

So I did it using regex, but the redirect seems to works I get the redirect, but www return timeout.

How can I solve this?

```
upstream wwwapp {   
    least_conn;                                                                                  
    server www-app:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
    server_name ~^(?!www\.)(?<domain>.+)$;
    return  301 $scheme://www.$domain$request_uri;
}

server {                                                                                                  
    listen       80;                                                                                      

    location / {                                                                                         
        proxy_pass http://wwwapp;                                                                     
        proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                          
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                          
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                                                           
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                     
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                
    }                                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
server {                                                                                                  
    listen       80;                                                                                      

    if ($host ~ ^(?!www\.)(?<domain>.+)$) {
        return  301 $scheme://www.$domain$request_uri;
    }

    location / {                                                                                         
        proxy_pass http://wwwapp;                                                                     
        proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                          
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                          
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                                                           
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                     
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                
    }                                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second `server` block does not have a `server_name` so it is unlikely to get selected to process any requests.

The first `server` block is the default and will get selected **even if the regex does not match**.

You should change the second `server` block, and either add a `server_name` statement or make it the `default_server`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.

Comment: this is the idea, to NOT have server_name, why? because I want every request to match this server section which will match the proxy. now I need to add redirect from non www to www. so I add the first section but it not end up. not sure why

Comment: I'm apply this configuration to all my servers - the LB is foward the reuqest to the currect nginx server. so I know the nginx seems to be unnecessary, but is just for redirection non-www to www

Comment: I explained why: the first server block is the default. You need to make the second server block the default. The best solution is to explicitly mark it as the `default_server`.